# Equality of two Determinants (transformation)

Tags: determinant, transformation

$det\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & -\lambda & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & -\lambda & 1\\1  & 1 & 1 & -\lambda\\\end{pmatrix} =  det\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda+3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\-\lambda + 3 & -\lambda & 1 & 1\\-\lambda+3 & 1 & -\lambda & 1\\-\lambda+3  & 1 & 1 & -\lambda\\\end{pmatrix}$

I fail to see how this transformation is justified. In the solution to my practice exercises, there is no explanation to this step. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the **columns** #2, #3 and #4 to the first.

Elementary row- and/or column-operations on your matrix do not change the value of its determinant.

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed that everyone only talks about the addition of rows when talking about matrices. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is not mentioned that often, because it directly follows from the fact that $\det A = \det A^T$

Answer (score 1):

Adding all the three last columns to the first one doesn't change the value of the determinant.

Comment: Is this exclusive to Determinants? Haven't seen this step done anywhere else.

Comment: This step is know as elementary operation.

Comment: Well hell. All our teachers ever told us was that the addition of rows was legitimate. Kind of funny. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call the first matrix $A$ and the second $B$. Note that $B=AE$ where 
$$
E=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But now $\det(B)=\det(AE)=\det(A)\det(E)=\det(A)\cdot 1=\det(A)$.